# How to split one word into multiple variables in bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Currently a variable is being set to something a string like this:

```
offs3.0
```

and I would like to split that into 2 variables

```
offs
3.0
```

How can i do it?

because i will use offs later.

```
if ("$1"=="offs")
here $1 is offs3.0
```

Comment: Do you want to split text and numbers? or something else. We need more info about splitting rules.

Answer (score 3):

using a bash regex

```
s=offs3.0
[[ $s =~ ^([^[:digit:]]+)(.*) ]] &&
   echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

```
offs - 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test if a variable contains `offs` you can use:

```
if [[ "$1" =~ "offs" ]]
then
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: Or, to test if a variable *starts with* the value: `[[ $1 == offs* ]]`

Comment: I want to use this method. but i have a new problem          in fact,  find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep -H SNR {} \; | grep "$1" > result.txt   if [[ "$1" =~ "offs" ]]
then
    # do something
fi

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using single sed also:

```
s='offs3.0'
(set -- $(sed 's/^\([a-z]*\)\(.*\)$/\1 \2/' <<< "$s") && echo "arg1=$1" "arg2=$2")

arg1=offs arg2=3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use the shell's built-in parameter substitution.

```
var='offs3.0'
echo "${var%%[.0-9]*}"
echo "${var##*[A-Za-z]}"
```

Comment: A similar answer was posted by @fedorqui, but then deleted.